# How do i call ajax function via button

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to post ajax to wordpress and im hitting a brick wall I have got this far thanks to you wonderfull guys but I need to no how my form calls this as at present its still saying file not found i replaced true file names with dummy text for securtiy of post.

This is my form what I need to no is what do i replace my action methods and submit button with to be able to call this function in functions.php

I need to no how to call this from a button withiin my form on its onclick I beleive

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  class="contact"   id="redemmpointsForm" >
            <div class="form-group">
            <h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>
                <input type="hidden" name="playerid" value="<?php echo $playerId;;?>" />
                  <input type="number"  valuemax="<?php echo $maxpoints;?>" name="points" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points do you wish to redeem." />                  
                   <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Comments">Comments?</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">submit</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                </div>
            </div>
```

```
        </form>

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_these_scripts' );
function load_these_scripts()   {
      wp_register_script( 'your_script', 'URI_OF_JS_THAT_MAKES_THE_AJAX_CALLS/scripts.js', false, false, true );
      wp_localize_script( 'my_ajax_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));  
}
```

Then in your scripts.js you need to make the AJAX calls like this:
Use this instead of the "data :"

```
$("#send_btn").click(function () {
    var formdata = $('form.contact').serialize();
    var allData = {
       action: 'php_function_name',
       data: formdata
    }

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : allData,
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               // Do something
            }
            else {
               // Do something else
            }
         }
      });
});
```

The `action: "php_function_name"` actually tells WP which function to call but you also need register that well. Do it like this, back in your functions.php (or plugin file):

```
add_action("wp_ajax_php_function_name", "php_function_name");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_php_function_name", "php_function_name");
function php_function_name() {

   // Some stuff here
   global $wpdb;
   $result = $wpdb->get_results( /* SQL code goes here */ );
   // Do something with $result
}
```

Make sure you register the function with both "wp_ajax" & "wp_ajax_norpiv" otherwise it will only work for logged in users.

Cheers

**Edit I ment to say my form is within a modal maybe its not finding the submit button ?**

```
<div id="thanks" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Redeem Points</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


<form class="form-horizontal"  class="contact"   id="redemmpointsForm" >
            <div class="form-group">
            <h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>
                <input type="hidden" name="playerid" value="<?php echo $playerId;;?>" />
                  <input type="number"  valuemax="<?php echo $maxpoints;?>" name="points" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points do you wish to redeem." />                  
                   <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Comments">Comments?</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="send_btn">Submit</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                </div>
            </div>
</form>



        </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
        </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
        </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal -->
```

**Edit to explain how far i HAVE GOT**

**Ok So now I have gotten this far my message box on the first line is firing. So its gathering my form data but its ignorning the number column some reason I am require this post to call the function  in wordpress functions.php**

```
wp_localize_script( 'inkthemes', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
add_action("wp_ajax_redeempoints", "redeempoints");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_redeempoints", "redeempoints");
function redeempoints() {

 global $wpdb;

 wp_mail( 'davidbuckleyni@gmail.com', 'The subject', 'The message' ); 
}
```

Jquery Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#send_btn").click(function(){

var datastring = $("#redemmpointsForm").serialize();

 var allData = {
       action: 'redeempoints',
       data: datastring
    }
      alert(datastring); // first message box fires

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : allData,
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
              alert('Call Ajax !!');  // this one does not
            }
            else {
               // Do something else
            }
         }
      });
});
 }); //Modal event Ends
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  input type as button and add id as js selecter `send_btn`.

```js
$("#send_btn").click(function () {
  alert('Call Ajax !!');  // for Your info
  
  var points = $('#points').val();
  var comments = $('#comments').val();
  
   alert(points+'  '+comments); // for Your info 
  
  var allData = {
       action: 'php_function_name',
       points: points,
       points:points
    }
   

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : allData,
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               // Do something
            }
            else {
               // Do something else
            }
         }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal"  class="contact"   id="redemmpointsForm" >
            <div class="form-group">
            <h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>
                <input type="hidden" name="playerid" value="<?php echo $playerId;;?>" />
                  <input type="number" id="points"  valuemax="<?php echo $maxpoints;?>" name="points" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points do you wish to redeem." />                  
                   <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Comments">Comments?</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="send_btn" value="submit"></button>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: its just loading the same page again for some reason i dont no why :-( its bringing up my dialog and submit button but its not getting to ajax working so its not

Comment: ment to say my button is within model maybe its not finding the button to beign with ???

Comment: Explain me.. i can't understand .. What to do ?

Comment: please see from the bold edit above Edit to explain how far i HAVE GOT

Comment: its not that thats the issue its not getting to success i am getting the values fine

Comment: Check in WordPress Code.. or Share here so i can check ... success  result get after run WP code.